# Qual a abreviação correta de "atenciosamente"?

Tags: ortografia, abreviações

Muitas vezes quando vou assinar um e-mail, fico na dúvida de como abreviar a palavra *atenciosamente*. Recebo e-mails em que a abreviação se dá de duas formas distintas, a primeira ***Att*** e a segunda ***At.te***. Qual a forma correta?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Att e At.te

De [Significados.com](http://www.significados.com.br/att/):

> **Att** é uma abreviação da palavra inglesa ***"attention"*** que, em Português, significa **"atenção"**.
>
> Corresponde à abreviatura **"A/C"** (ao cuidado de) que se escreve em documentos ou encomendas cujo destinatário se pretende especificar.
>
> É muito frequente em e-mails formais o uso da saudação final **"Atenciosamente"** reduzida para **"Att"**.
>
> Essa expressão costuma ser escrita antes da assinatura, como uma maneira de encerrar a mensagem de forma delicada e educada.
>
> Contudo, a forma reduzida da expressão **"Atenciosamente"** é, por convenção, aceita como **"At.te"** e não **"Att"**, como usualmente se escreve.
>
> Alguns guias de estilo, no entanto, recomendam que a forma mais delicada e elegante de finalizar uma mensagem é escrever o termo **"Atenciosamente"** na sua forma por extenso, sem fazer uso da palavra abreviada.
>
> Convém ressaltar que a forma ***"Attention"*** (ao cuidado de) usada nos países de língua inglesa, para especificar o destinatário da mensagem é corretamente abreviada como **"Attn:"** (sem esquecer os dois-pontos).
>
> Em alguns casos também se verifica as abreviaturas **"FTAO"** *(For The Attention Of)* ou simplesmente **"FAO"** *(For Attention Of)*.
>
> Em inglês, por vezes **att** também pode ser a abreviação de ***"attached"*** (significa anexado) ou ***"attorney"*** (que significa advogado).

Comment: Em inglês, por vezes att também pode ser a abreviação de "attached" (significa anexado) ou "attorney" (que significa advogado).
Pergunta: att tem que ser precedido de . ou ,
att
obrigado

Comment: Em português, att não deve ser usado, nem com ponto nem com vírgula.

Answer (score 4):

Segundo a [Academia Brasileira de Letras (“Reduções”)](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/reducoes), *At.te* é a redução oficial de *atenciosamente* na língua portuguesa.

Answer (score 1):

A abreviação de atenciosamente é: ***atte***.

Fonte: Curso de Língua Portuguesa Professor Filemon. Brasília – DF.